# SQL/DB2 How to find the number of times an ID appeared in a year?

Tags: sql, db2

What's the best/easiest way to find the number of times an ID has appeared Per Year and get the results for multiple columns. This seems much harder than I initially thought, unless I am overlooking something.

```
Table Example

ID    Year 
A     2010
B     2011
B     2012
C     2011
C     2011
C     2012

Desired Output
ID 2010_CNT 2011_CNT 2012_CNT
A  1        0        0
B  0        1        1   
C  0        2        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your values are fixed you can simply use a conditional aggregation:

```
Select
id,
sum(case when YEAR='2010' then 1 else 0 end) as Y_2010,
sum(case when YEAR='2011' then 1 else 0 end) as Y_2011,
sum(case when YEAR='2012' then 1 else 0 end) as Y_2012
from Example
group by id
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I need while also being very readable, I never thought to use sum in this way!

Answer (score 1):

```
 WITH CTE(ID,YEAR)AS
  (
     SELECT  'A',     2010  UNION ALL
     SELECT 'B',     2011 UNION ALL
     SELECT 'B',     2012 UNION ALL
     SELECT 'C',     2011 UNION ALL
     SELECT 'C',     2011 UNION ALL
     SELECT 'C',     2012 
  )
  SELECT C.ID,
     SUM(CASE WHEN C.YEAR=2010 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS Y_2010_CNT,
     SUM(CASE WHEN C.YEAR=2011 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS Y_2011_CNT,
     SUM(CASE WHEN C.YEAR=2012 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS Y_2012_CNT 
   FROM CTE AS C
   GROUP BY C.ID
   ORDER BY C.ID;
```

You can use conditional aggregation (example is above. CTE represents data you have provided)